# Python Compile Mixed C and C++ Extension

Tags: python, c++, c, setuptools, pybind11

I'm attempting to compile libspng with PyBind11 so I can easily convert image data into a numpy array.

The compilation process requires compiling a few C files and then linking them to C++. However, I'm not sure how to do this with Python setuptools. I've so far been compiling all C++ or all C modules in my practice, but on clang, this results in problems when I mix the pybind11 file with the C files.

Is there a simple way that I'm missing to compile and link the C files to C++ within setup.py?

I tried building an extension for libspng, but I wasn't sure how to reference the compiled shared object file which was in the build folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I would include the C files within an `extern "C"` block and then reference them via C++ wrappers that pybind11 can export. For libspng, you can use the `extra_link_args` argument. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#other-options).

Comment: Thanks Chris~ The two C libraries I'm references already include `extern "C"` under a preprocessor flag. Can you show me an example of what to put in the `extra_link_args`? I have some familiarity with compilation, but I'm weaker at linking.

Comment: Static linking is probably easiest. In which case `extra_link_args = ['-L/path/to/lib', '-l:spng']` should do it. Alternatively there is a `library_dirs = ['/path/to/lib']` (if it's installed in a non-standard location that is). Be careful to ensure it actually *is* linking statically, this can be a bit of a pain on [some platforms](https://jonwillia.ms/2018/02/02/static-linking). Alternatively just try the dynamic linking with `-lspng`, but make sure it can find the .so at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! This is a stupid question, but does spng need to be compiled into .o files before static linking is possible or will it allow the compiler to figure out that they need to be compiled separately? Should I split the extension in two so that the compilation can proceed in stages?

Comment: are you building libspng with cmake? It should create a `libspng_static.a` that you can link to directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's helpful (and because I am procrastinating) I built a small demo based on the spng example

```c
// pywrappers.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>
extern "C" {
    #include <spng/spng.h>
}

namespace py = pybind11;

std::pair<size_t, size_t> get_size(const std::string& filename)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");

    if (fp == nullptr)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        throw std::runtime_error("File not found");
    }

    spng_ctx* ctx = spng_ctx_new(0);

    spng_set_crc_action(ctx, SPNG_CRC_USE, SPNG_CRC_USE);

    size_t limit = 1024 * 1024 * 64;
    spng_set_chunk_limits(ctx, limit, limit);

    spng_set_png_file(ctx, fp);

    struct spng_ihdr ihdr;
    spng_get_ihdr(ctx, &ihdr);

    spng_ctx_free(ctx);
    fclose(fp);

    return std::make_pair<size_t, size_t>(ihdr.width, ihdr.height);
}


PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m)
{
    m.def("get_size", &get_size);
}
```

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import pybind11

SPNG_SOURCE = './libspng-0.7.1' # Wherever you put the spng headers and .a

libfoo = Extension(
    'foo',
    sources=['pywrappers.cpp'],
    extra_compile_args = ['-std=c++14'],
    include_dirs=[SPNG_SOURCE, pybind11.get_include()],
    extra_link_args=['-lspng_static','-lz'],
    library_dirs=[SPNG_SOURCE]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name = 'foo',
        ext_modules=[libfoo],
    )
```

Build the extension as usual with e.g. `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. Then for example

```py
import foo
foo.get_size('stuff.png')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for going above and beyond Chris! Let me test this out and then I'll mark this as accepted. I suppose I'll have to engineer the deployment to generate the static libraries first.

Comment: Thank you Chris! I ended up calling subprocess.run("make", cwd="./vendor") to generate the archive file and then used your code as a skeleton. I created a PR for pyspng here: https://github.com/nurpax/pyspng/pull/6

Comment: Np. If you are using CICD then you can also build these external libraries in e.g. `.gitlab-ci.yml` or `tox` or similar. The nice thing about static linking here is that the packages can then be deployed as binary wheels, the downside being you need different wheels for each platform and python version.